# Using Breadth First Search and inorder traversal to analyze the validity of a really large binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was thinking about the different techniques to check the validity of a binary search tree. Naturally, the invariant that needs to be maintained is that the left subtree must be less than or equal to the current node, which in turn should be less than or equal to the right subtree. There are a couple of different ways to tackle this problem: The first is to check the constraints for values on each subtree and can be outlined like this (in Java, for integer nodes):

```
public static boolean isBST(TreeNode node, int lower, int higher){

   if(node == null) return true;
   else if(node.data < lower || node.data > higher) return false;
   return isBST(node.left, lower, node.data) && isBST(node.right, node.data, higher);
}
```

There is also another way to accomplish this using an inOrder traversal where you keep track of the previous element and make sure the progression is strictly non-decreasing. Both these methods explore the left subtrees first though, and in the event we have an inconsistency in the middle of the root's right subtree, what is the recommended path? I know that a BFS variant could be used, but would it be possible to use multiple techniques at the same time and is that recommended? For example, we could to a BFS, an inorder and a reverseInorder and return the moment there is a failure detected. This could only maybe be desirable for really large trees in order to reduce the average runtime at the cost of a bit more space and multiple threads accessing the same data structure. Ofcourse, if we're using a simple iterative solution for inorder solution (NOT a morris traversal that modifies the tree) we will be using up O(lgN) space.

Comment: Can you describe more about your setup? In any determinisic algorithm there will be some worst-case tree that evades detection until the last minute, and any optimizations you can perform will almost certainly have to be based on your expectation about the input trees.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this to depend on your precise situation. In particular, what is the probability that your tree will fail to be binary, and the expected depth at which the failure will occur.

For example, if it is likely that the tree is correctly binary, then it would be wasteful to use 3 multiple techniques as the overall runtime for a valid tree will be roughly tripled.

Comment: The only certainty here is that the binary tree takes up most of the space on a single machine. If we had some idea of "where" the BST property is likely to fail, then the problem would be trivial as we could apply the appropriate technique; if we expect the BST failure in the rightmost end of the root's right subtree, then we can do a reverse inorder walk to figure things out. If we expect a failure closer up to the root (but once again in the right subtree), then using a BFS might not be a bad idea.

Comment: The question stands: In the event that you're just not sure, is it advisable to apply all 3 approaches concurrently (say as Futures) and since they don't modify any part of the tree, we can just wait for any one of the techniques to fail and then return the result. Otherwise we would have all 3 techniques play out and we would get the result once they're done.

Answer (score 0):

What about [iterative deepening depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)?

It is generally (asymptotically) as fast as breadth-first search (and also finds any early failure), but uses as little memory as depth-first search.

It would typically look something like this:

```
boolean isBST(TreeNode node, int lower, int higher, int depth)
{
  if (depth == 0)
    return true;
  ...
  isBST(..., depth-1)
  ...
}
```

Caller:

```
boolean failed = false;
int treeHeight = height(root);
for (int depth = 2; depth <= treeHeight && !failed; depth++)
  failed = !isBST(root, -INFINITY, INFINITY, depth);
```